# Is there a way to override type in the interface in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to get into TS now and to add it to my React Native app.

Let's say I have a component like this:

```
interface Props {
  name: string;
  onChangeText: (args: { name: string; value: string }) => void;
  style: ReactNative.TextStyle;
}

export class Input extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  static defaultProps = {
    onChangeText: null,
    style: {},
  };

  handleTextChange = (text: string) => {
    const { name, onChangeText } = this.props;
    if (onChangeText) {
      onChangeText({ name, value: text });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { style: propsStyle, onChangeText, ...restProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <ReactNative.TextInput
        style={[style, propsStyle]}
        onChangeText={this.handleTextChange}
        {...restProps}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

But if I try to use this component somehow like this:

```
<Input
  name='title'
  value={this.state.title}
  onChangeText={this.handleFieldChange}
/>
```

I'm getting an error:

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes...

But I can't inherit `Props` from `ReactNative.TextInputProps` because in this case I override `onChangeText`'s interface and start getting another error.
So, is there a way to make it this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like

```
type BaseProps = ReactNative.TextInputProps;
interface Props extends BaseProps {
  name: string;
  onChangeText: (args: { name: string; value: string }) => void;
  style: ReactNative.TextStyle;
}
```

In case your custom properties collide with the base ones, you can remove them from the extended interface:

```
type BaseProps = Pick<ReactNative.TextInputProps, Exclude<keyof ReactNative.TextInputProps, "name" | "onChangeText">>;
interface Props extends BaseProps {
```

More info on `Pick<..., Exclude<...>>` (a.k.a `Omit<>`) is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you define an index signature on your interface, you can give it any prop as long as it matches the signature type:

```
interface TextStyle { fontSize: number }

interface Args {
  name: string;
  value: string;
}

type onChangeText = (args: Args) => void;

interface Props {
  [key: string]: string | TextStyle | onChangeText;
  name: string;
  onChangeText(args: { name: string; value: string }): void;
  style?: TextStyle;
}
```

and now

```
const props: Props = {
  name: 'title', 
  onChangeText: ({name, string}) => false,
  value: 'value' // <- no error 
}
```

But be aware that something like this will fail:

```
const props: Props = {
  name: 'title', 
  onChangeText: ({name, string}) => false,
  value: 10 // <- cannot be assigned
}
```

unless you update the index signature to include that type